# Facebook API in python is getting an error when trying to use get_ad_sets

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads

I need to get some facebook ads data from my company to apply an AI algorithm for some task, the original code (with app_secret, app_id,... unhidden) returns an expection. The following code just differs from the original due to I'm omiting privacy data such as token, some ids,...(with app_secret,... hidden)[read the comments] in my script:

```
import facebook_business
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebook_business.adobjects.adset import AdSet
from facebook_business.adobjects.campaign import Campaign
access_token = 'hidden'###token to get my APP in AP FB
app_secret = 'hidden'###secret ID of my app
app_id = 'hidden'##id of my app
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token, app_secret=app_secret, app_id=app_id)
account_id = '10205819408979407'## the account ID I'd like to scrap
ad_account = AdAccount(account_id)
ad_sets = ad_account.get_ad_sets(fields=[
    AdSet.Field.id,
    AdSet.Field.name,
    AdSet.Field.created_time,
    AdSet.Field.targeting,
    AdSet.Field.daily_budget,
    AdSet.Field.optimization_goal,
    # Add other desired parameters
])
for ad_set in ad_sets:
    ad_set_id = ad_set[AdSet.Field.id]
    ad_set_name = ad_set[AdSet.Field.name]
    ad_set_created_time = ad_set[AdSet.Field.created_time]

    # Retrieve reach, frequency, and impressions metrics
    ad_set_insights = ad_set.get_insights(fields=[
        'reach',
        'frequency',
        'impressions'
    ])
    for insight in ad_set_insights:
        reach = insight['reach']
        frequency = insight['frequency']
        impressions = insight['impressions']

        # Process the retrieved data as needed
        print(f"Ad Set ID: {ad_set_id}")
        print(f"Ad Set Name: {ad_set_name}")
        print(f"Creation Time: {ad_set_created_time}")
        print(f"Reach: {reach}")
        print(f"Frequency: {frequency}")
        print(f"Impressions: {impressions}")
        print("---")
```

the exception of original code is given as (edited to omit id):

```
  Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  GET
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/10205819408979407/insights
  Params:  {'fields': 'reach,frequency,impressions'}
  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'hidden' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
        "type": "GraphMethodException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "AjpZMc8BkQQQMucBcwr1i_W"
      }
```

The such auxiliar fb app (not the code) to scrap data was created by the this logic flux:'https://developers.facebook.com/apps/?show_reminder=true > others > none > putting any name > create app' and setting needed token permisions (ads_read, ads_management and business_management) at GRAPHIC API interface in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/.

What I've tried

1. Verify the facebook account which stores the ad FB data. (This is verified now but still returns me the error)
2. Get me as an admin over all this data disponible at ads manager.
3. Set the ads_read, ads_management, and business_management as permitions in my token.

NOTE: the account_id is not from my facebook account but is from the acc which owns the data

Comment: _"the account_id is not from my facebook account but is from the acc which owns the data"_ - then what makes you think that you should have access? What is the connection to your account?

Comment: I'm as adm in the campaign management  regarding the data from the facebook ads (where data is stored in), the account where the data is stored is just an ads fb acc it's not a fb account with login and password, I think it's not even possible logging in the such account. I think I'm misusing endpoint

Comment: "As an admin in ad management, creating the app within the business account that has access to the ad account will provide you with the necessary privileges and enable you to execute the code effectively." chat gpt stated me that

Comment: I really need to solve this problem please try contact me at chat and if we manage to solve it you can post your solution

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make a call to the Ad Account endpoint your Ad Account must always have the prefix 'act_'... in your case it would be **'act_10205819408979407'**